# Python: Can ZeroMQ have setup a callback to be called once it received a message?

Tags: python-2.7, zeromq

I'm a new learner of ZeroMQ. I want to know if there is an approach to set a callback which can be invoked once a message comes, I mean once data exist in the stream.

I do not want to use a thread and a loop to indicate data in, and then invoke the callback.

Do you have any idea how to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ZeroMQ native API since v2.x till recent v4.2+ has never used a callback associated with low-level internalities. All API services were designed so as to respond to `.poll( 0 )` or `.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )` methods and let thte user application decide and act accordingly.

If indeed in a need to use hardwired callbacks, there are two possible directions forwards:

**1 )** use the common python tool - the **`Tkinter.mainloop()`** factory, where one can setup a blocking handler with a **`StringVar()`** instance, being set by `.recv()` like this ( here forgivingly a blocking manner ) : **`aStringVAR.set( aSocket.recv() )`**, onto which one has also associated a Tracer, that calls the desired callback-handler in response to the StringVar getting a new value stored.

```
>>> #-----------------------------------------------FAST MOCK-UP EXAMPLE
>>> import Tkinter as tk                          # python27
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> root.protocol( "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit() )
'3071841620Ldestroy'
>>> #------VAR-------------------------------------IMPORTANT TOOL:
>>> aStringVAR = tk.StringVar()
>>> aStringVAR.set( "_init_" )

>>> def aKeyPressEventHANDLER( anEvent ): # SIMPLE EventHANDLER,
        #                                 #        also ignites remote responsive processes
...     aTemplate = "[KEY]::{3: >10s}\n<s/n>::{0: >10d}\n(=@=)::{1: > 10d}\n^from::({5:})"
...     sString   = aTemplate.format( anEvent.serial,
...                                   anEvent.time,
...                                   anEvent.char,
...                                   anEvent.keysym,
...                                   anEvent.keysym_num,
...                               str(anEvent.widget )
...                               )
...     aStringVAR.set( sString ) # <----------------- emulated instead of  aSocket.recv()
...     print sString
... 
>>> #----VAR_TRACER----------------------------------------[#1]
>>> def aVAR_TRACER_A( p1_quasiNAME, p2_indexOrEmptyString, p3_accessMODE ):
...     print "aVAR_TRACER_A()-called::(on){0:} traced_event({1:})".format( str( p1_quasiNAME ), str( p3_accessMODE ) )
...     # ###############=[A]#######
...     # < do some task =[A] here >
...     # ###############=[A]#######
...     print "aVAR_TRACER_A()         [{0:}]".format(   str( root.globalgetvar( p1_quasiNAME ) ).replace( " ", "" ) )
...
>>> #-----VAR_A_tracer_ID------------------------------"w" EVENT SNIFFER WAITING FOR ASSIGNMENT INTO aStringVAR
>>> aTraceVAR_A_tracer_ID = aStringVAR.trace_variable( "w", aVAR_TRACER_A )

aVAR_TRACER_A()-called::(on)PY_VAR0 traced_event(w)
aVAR_TRACER_A()         [[KEY]::a<s/n>::832(=@=)::88486992^from::(.)]
[KEY]::         a
<s/n>::       832
(=@=)::  88486992
^from::(.)
aVAR_TRACER_A()-called::(on)PY_VAR0 traced_event(w)
aVAR_TRACER_A()         [[KEY]::KP_6<s/n>::832(=@=)::88509107^from::(.)]
[KEY]::      KP_6
<s/n>::       832
(=@=)::  88509107
^from::(.)
aVAR_TRACER_A()-called::(on)PY_VAR0 traced_event(w)
aVAR_TRACER_A()         [[KEY]::KP_Multiply<s/n>::832(=@=)::88541180^from::(.)]
[KEY]::KP_Multiply
<s/n>::       832
(=@=)::  88541180
^from::(.)
```

or more complex, if using directly injected `Tkinter` virtual-events :

```
################################################ SETUP EVENT-ROUTING Injector

self.aSigFromZMQ = "<<aVirtualEventSignalledFromZMQ_LAYER>>"

self.bind( self.aSigFromZMQ, anEventHANDLER )
#   |
#   .bind <<virtual_EventNAME>> altogether with <anEventHANDLER>-call


################################################ Context-fully TRIGGER Injector

self.event_generate( self.aSigFromZMQ, aSigContextDICT )
#   |
#   .event_generate( <eventNameId>, **args )  #   triggers <eventNameId>
#                                             # + passes **args, that allows
#                                             #          to set <keyword>=<value> pairs for Event-fields,
#                                             #          that are passed to anEventHANDLER via <Event>-object .
```

**2 )** change ZeroMQ and use rather [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg), resp. the NNG new API, where callback mechanics could get associated with socket-state/events.

Comment: Thank you. It's very helpful to me